Issue with web scraping in R using rvest
I am trying to scrape political speeches from this website: https://www.narendramodi.in/category/text-speeches
Using rvest package, I just started with this code:
modi <- "https://www.narendramodi.in/category/text-speeches"  
html <- read_html(modi)

However, read_html runs on for hours without stopping. I cannot find a workaround or a reason why this is happening? Should I just leave the code running for more time?
So far I have tried: turning off my VPN, read_html works for other webpages, robotstxt indicates that scraping is allowed for the website.
I was expecting this to work so that I could go on further and use selectorgadget to scrape the speeches on the webpage but I am unable to go further than this as the read_html function just does not stop running.
Any help/advice would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Use httr to retrieve the webpage then rvest to extract the data.
### Packages
library(httr)
library(rvest)

### Specify the url you want to get
url="https://www.narendramodi.in/category/text-speeches"

### Download the page with httr by specifying user-agent and encoding type
response=GET(
  url,
  add_headers(
    `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0",
    `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate"
  )
)

### Extract the data (titles for example) with rvest
content(response) %>%
  html_elements(xpath = '//div[@class="speechesItemLink left_class "]/a') %>% 
  html_text2()

Output :
[1] "This government, led by a son of the poor, has given top priority to the welfare of the poor: PM Modi in Kalyan"                
[2] "If you work for 10 hours then I will work for 18 hours and this is Modi's guarantee to 140 crore Indians: PM Modi in Pratapgarh"
[3] "There is no chance of Congress-SP emerging victorious in Bhadohi: PM Modi in Bhadohi, UP"                                       
[4] "CAA is a testimony to Modi's guarantee: PM Modi in Lalganj, UP"                                                                 
[5] "We've never discriminated based on religion; our schemes benefit everyone: PM Modi in Dindori"                                  
[6] "When there is a weak government like Congress, it weakens the country as well, says PM Modi in Koderma, Jharkhand"              
[7] "The priority of RJD and Congress is not you, the people, but their own vote bank: PM Modi in Hajipur"                           
[8] "Your dreams are my resolve and for this 24/7 for 2047: PM Modi in Saran"                                                        
[9] "The jungle raj of the RJD pushed Bihar back for decades: PM Modi in Muzaffarpur"

